# No types in Eclipse Indigo's "New server" window

Tags: eclipse, ide, jboss, eclipse-indigo

I want to set up a new JBoss Server in Eclipse Indigo.

But unfortunately there are no types in the "New server" window for me to choose from. Clicking "Download additional server adapters" also doesn't help, since the JBoss server can't be found there.

As far as I can remember, Eclipse Helios offered a way to set up a JBoss server.

[image: See here for a screenshot of the empty "New Server" window.]

P. S.: I'm using the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers.

Comment: You might want to check the Eclipse error log (found under `.metadata\.log` in your workspace).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That version of Eclipse is missing most of the web tools you will want.  Use the "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" version instead: http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigor.

Otherwise, you will need to install the Web Tools Project (WTP) modules yourself.  The servers will be there, too.

Comment: Now I'm using the JEE edition and the server types are here again.

Comment: I installed already some WTP plugins, starting off a Java Eclipse installation. Do you know exactly which WTP plugins are needed to see some server type? Thanks

Comment: nevermind, found: `WST server adapters` in `Web Tools Platform (WTP)`

Answer (score 6):

You can add Java EE Development tools in to the existing IDE too.

Go to

- Help
- Install New Software
- Select "Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno" in the work with drop down
- Expand Web,XML,Java EE and OSGi Development & Select Java EE Developer  Tools.
- Also add WST Server Adapters, JST Server Adapters and JST Server Adapters Extensions

Comment: Actually, not only `Java EE Developer Tools`, but also `WST Server Adapters`, `JST Server Adapters` and `JST Server Adapters Extensions`.